# Iterating field calculations in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, error-000539

I was successful in adding multiple fields but had trouble running multiple field calculations in a loop. Now what I want is loop through these existing fields listed in `mult_fields` variable and fill values in the fields newly created through the `div_fields` variable. I was hoping something like the following would work, rather than using search cursors.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env


# set the environments
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "C:\\WORKSPACE\\mm_agallocation.gdb"
inFeature = "myFeature"
div_fields = ("divpa_whea"  , "divpa_maiz", "divpa_barl", "divpa_sorg",
                  "divpa_sorg", "divpa_grou","divaa_whea", "divaa_maiz", "divaa_barl", 
                  "divaa_sorg", "divaa_sorg", "divaa_grou")
for i in div_fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(myFeature, i, "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE")

mult_fields = ("mpa_whea"  , "mpa_maiz", "mpa_barl", "mpa_sorg",
               "mpa_sorg", "mpa_grou","maa_whea","maa_maiz", 
               "maa_barl", "maa_sorg", "maa_sorg", "maa_grou")

# all field names given in 'mult_fields' are already in "myFeature"
for i in div_fields:
    for k in mult_fields:
        expression = "!k! * !k!"
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeature, i, expression, "PYTHON")
```

I however get the following error. I'd imagine it is the way I am specifying the `expression` that is giving me the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2727, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Invalid field mult_fields
Failed to execute (CalculateField)
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's the way you're referring to your iteration variables in side a Python string.
Why not use a Update Cursor? The newer ones in `arcpy.da` are pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks! you are right, but I have arcgis 10.0 the `arcpy.da` came after that..

Comment: You have provided two pieces of code but not a working code snippet (that starts with `import arcpy`) so that we can quickly test to try and reproduce.  With that, or to help create that, I would start by `print`ing out the contents of `div_fields` and `mult_fields` prior to their last usage.

Comment: Rather than `k * k` you may want to consider using `k ** 2`, once you get the Python Parser bit sorted out.

Comment: thanks I've edited the question accordingly. I'm going to try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it currently stands, your nested `for` loops are doing something akin to this:

```
div_fields = ["f1", "f2", "f3"]

mult_fields = ["g1", "g2", "g3"]

for t,i in enumerate(div_fields):
    for k in mult_fields:
        print("{}Calcing field {} with {}".format("\t"*t, i, "'!{0}! * !{0}!'".format(k)))
>>>
Calcing field f1 with '!g1! * !g1!'
Calcing field f1 with '!g2! * !g2!'
Calcing field f1 with '!g3! * !g3!'
    Calcing field f2 with '!g1! * !g1!'
    Calcing field f2 with '!g2! * !g2!'
    Calcing field f2 with '!g3! * !g3!'
        Calcing field f3 with '!g1! * !g1!'
        Calcing field f3 with '!g2! * !g2!'
        Calcing field f3 with '!g3! * !g3!'
```

This is *probably* not what you want (after all, each  of the 12 fields is being overwritten 12 times--you're calling `Calculate Field` 144 times!). I'm assuming you want your wheat fields to be calculated with wheat, sorghum with sorghum, etc. To solve this, use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for t,(i,k) in enumerate(zip(div_fields, mult_fields)):
    print("{}Calcing field {} with {}".format("\t"*t, i, "'!{0}! * !{0}!'".format(k)))
>>>
Calcing field f1 with '!g1! * !g1!'
    Calcing field f2 with '!g2! * !g2!'
        Calcing field f3 with '!g3! * !g3!'
```

As @Paulo pointed out, you are hardcoding your `k` variable, which means that `Calculate Field` is attempting to find a field named `k`. You don't need to wrap it in quotes, so here it is with your data now:

```
for i,k in zip(div_fields, mult_fields):
   arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeature, i, "!{0}! * !{0}!".format(k), "PYTHON_9.3")
   # or "!{}! ** 2".format(k)
```

As a tip, you'll probably find it simpler to work with if you use more descriptive variable names. Reserve `i`,`j`,`k` for counters. Since your list is named `div_fields`, iterate over it with `for div_field in div_fields` or similar.

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you! I am now well educated about `zip`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change `expression = "!k! * !k!"` to

```
expression = "'!" + k + "! * !" + k + "!'"
```

Comment: it gave me `invalid syntax`..I'll try wrapping it with a double quote.

Comment: @yanes, It's a bit easier to work with if you use `str.format()`: `"'!{0}! * !{0}!'".format(k)`

Comment: Ah, edited it so that the string would contain the single quotes. Though the nice string-formatting in the comment here by @Paul is perhaps more elegant :)